# Ayuda error JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario, el cual dentro de el sube un archivo de imagen, al ejecutarlo me sale un error en consola

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'endValue' of undefined
>       at HTMLBodyElement.KeyUp (listen.js:1)

Al rellenar los campos y darle al boton SAVE, me salta al mensaje de error de envío, he estado revisando y no tengo ningún elemento llamado "endValue" y no se mucho sobre Javascript.
Les agradecería mucho si hay alguien que pueda ayudarme

Este es mi codigo:
form.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p class="statusMsg"></p>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fupForm" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Nombre del negocio</label>
                <input type="text" name="id_user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>" style="display: none;" readonly>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre del negocio" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="telefono">Teléfono</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Número de teléfono" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="descripcion" id="descripcion" placeholder="Ingresa una pequeña descripción de lo que vendes." required=""></textarea> 
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="file">Imagen</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file" required />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger submitBtn" value="SAVE"/>
        </form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $("#fupForm").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'submit.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('#fupForm').css("opacity",".5");
            },
            success: function(msg){
                $('.statusMsg').html('');
                if(msg == 'ok'){
                    $('#fupForm')[0].reset();
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#34A853">Form data submitted successfully.</span>');
                }else{
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#EA4335">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                }
                $('#fupForm').css("opacity","");
                $(".submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    });

    //file type validation
    $("#file").change(function() {
        var file = this.files[0];
        var imagefile = file.type;
        var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
        if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2]))){
            alert('Please select a valid image file (JPEG/JPG/PNG).');
            $("#file").val('');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Este es el submit.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['telefono']) || !empty($_POST['descripcion']) || !empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
    $uploadedFile = '';
    if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["type"])){
        $fileName = time().'_'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $valid_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $file_extension = end($temporary);
        if((($_FILES["hard_file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")) && in_array($file_extension, $valid_extensions)){
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = "uploads/".$fileName;
            if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)){
                $uploadedFile = $fileName;
            }
        }
    }
    $user = $_POST['id_user'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $tel = $_POST['telefono'];
    $desc = $_POST['descripcion'];
    $dbHost = 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = 'root';
    $dbPassword = '';
    $dbName = 'cones';
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    if($db->connect_error){
        die("Unable to connect database: " . $db->connect_error);
    }
    $insert = $db->query("INSERT info_negocio (fkusers,file_name,nom_negocio,telefono,descripcion) VALUES ('".$user"','".$uploadedFile."','".$name."','".$tel."','".$desc."')");
    echo $insert?'ok':'err';
}
?>
```

Comment: El error ocurre en la primera línea de un archivo llamado `listen.js`, debes revisar ese archivo.

Comment: El código incluido no muestra donde se carga `listen.js`. Por favor lee [mcve], intenta reproducir el error usando el menor número de líneas de código y edita tu pregunta según corresponda.